# How can I enforce all properties from an optional intersection

Tags: typescript

I have an `<Icon/>` JSX component that optionally accepts `link` & `title` props, but when one of them is provided, the other MUST ALSO be provided. **How do I enforce that?**

```
interface IconProps {
  width?: number
  height?: number
  alt?: string
  src: string
}

interface IconWithLink {
  link: string
  title: string
}

declare function BetterIcon({ height, width, src, alt, ...rest }: BetterIconProps): any
```

I tried various combinations and original interfaces with extends, but nothing worked.

```
type BetterIconProps = IconProps | (IconProps & IconWithLink)
type BetterIconProps = IconProps & (IconWithLink | {})
```

I get a correct intellisense that the property is not optional, but no error is displayed when the property is not provided.
[image]

---

**I eventually made it work** with this combo, but it is most inconvenient when I need to introduce yet another optional group...

```
type BetterIconProps = IconWithoutLink | IconWithLink

interface IconProps {
  width?: number
  height?: number
  alt?: string
  src: string
}

interface IconWithoutLink extends IconProps {
  link?: never
  title?: never
}

interface IconWithLink extends IconProps {
  link: string
  title: string
}
```

[image]

### Is there some better, more generic way to do that?

Comment: I'd probably do what you're doing, but abstract that "all-or-none" into a type function, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m049rm) shows.  Does that work for you? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That is good enough to provided as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract that "all-or-none" behavior into its own type function, like

```
type AllOrNone<T> = T | { [K in keyof T]?: never };
```

And then you can compose these as necessary:

```
interface IconProps {
    width?: number
    height?: number
    alt?: string
    src: string
}

interface IconWithLink {
    link: string
    title: string
}

interface SomeOtherGroup {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}

type BetterIconProps = IconProps &
    AllOrNone<IconWithLink> &
    AllOrNone<SomeOtherGroup>;
```

Testing it out:

```
const badProps: BetterIconProps = {
    src: "abc",
    link: "oops" 
} // error, property link is not as expected

const stillBadProps: BetterIconProps = {
    src: "abc",
    link: "def",
    title: "ghi",
    foo: "oops"
} // error, property bar is missing

const goodProps: BetterIconProps = {
    src: "abc",
    link: "def",
    title: "ghi",
    foo: "jkl",
    bar: 123
} // okay
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEA2iDyAnAcgewHbQDwAqAfLALyyGwA+sA3rANoDSsAljrANbThYBmlALoB+AFyw8AN2hpYAXwDcIDqFn8AhgGM4ASS24ACmiyQAzvWCxrsAO5sAJqAAW4yQFcAtgCNZVm87QbADmzqBuOF6+aP7WGojhEmagaBzBsbBmaFpJKWnA8io4amiaOrD6uADqbC4AMhxcljawiI25qTjpLaC1iNAd+YXAquracADKWJ7QKC6yAOIm7pDNNvxYWINdGd4aaBKRPn7DEDCwAELQoCWVOMamFhR3D+awAGQZSKiYuAR3NXqjVInxa33Q2Dw+CmMzmgTQSywK2IymABhwyVgewcrzMEiuN1kLxMbwodAyWRysAARBpvFpqQAaDJtHBcCTUzbmamwAqwAD0-NgshMaEZsEgJNkEFajXYFhwWFAsA0FmgAA8YFo1A4QOjMck2MgLhocSS8Zdrrd0bjyGtrJSOXSGcyWqz2TSHNB+EyMr1QP0OaE2L6WhstjSuWZqXzBcK0KLxZLTNLwFj9vLYJ42GYzPk0bhMcFNmbHvirUSbea7eSWo6ac7QzZ3RyvT7XTZ-YGacGm9ZwxyAFZcRB99MHWAARgATABmWNCrBcDTgEDAIA)